# Help review this calculation of Torsion of a space curve

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

I am working on a practice set and this is given as a guide to solving for torsion of a space curve.
[image: one]

$\color{red}{\textrm{My issue is this following part}}$
[image: 2]

I have that $( r'(t) \times r''(t)) \cdot r'''(t) ) = 46080$ , $\color{red}{\textrm{not 92160}}$

Can someone check this and share what I am missing?

Comment: Your answer seems right.

Comment: The 4608? Do you have any idea why they would double it??